# Communication child -> parent process php fork

Tags: php, fork

i know when i fork the proccess the child proccess gain a new copy of the memory i can access to the parent variables but i can't modify.

```
<?php

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     $b = "XXX";
     // we are the parent         
} else {
     // we are the child
     echo $b; // prints XXX
     $b = "YYY"; // only changes $b in the child, $b in parent isn't affected
}

?>
```

how i can sent a message from the child to the parent? i need sent a array structure

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: sorry i update the problem is "how i can sent a message from the child to the parent?". i'm not good in english.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are two seperate processes, there is no direct method of communication. You could have the child store the information in a commonly reachable location, and have the parent pull from there though. (For example through using a database or a file)

Of course, this'll lead you deep into Multithreaded Programming territory with all of its associated troubles.

Comment: In that case what would be the best way to store counters. example many childs may increment the same key